# How can I limit categories displaying in posts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to show the limited categories displaying in my post. Here is my blog page.

https://k2fly.com/blog/

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NykiC.png)

Kindly visit the page and give me advice how can i reduce category number displaying.
I have tried with this codes but not working

```
<?php
// display 7 random categories

$cats ='';
$categories=get_categories('posts_per_page=5&exclude=' . $GLOBALS[asides_id]);
$rand_keys = array_rand($categories, 4);

foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {

    $cats .= $categories[$key]->term_id .',';

}

wp_list_categories('title_li=&include='.$cats);
?>
```

Comment: Use this $args = array(
       'orderby' => 'name',
       'number' => 10
    );
    $job_categories = get_categories( $args );
    foreach ($job_categories as $cat) :

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the `get_categories` function in the following way?

```
$categories=get_categories( array(
'number' => 5,
'exclude' => $GLOBALS[asides_id]
) );
```

Comment: can you please clear me where can i add this get_categories function? i am new to php

Comment: is it like this? $cats ='';
$categories=get_categories( array(
'number' => 5,
'exclude' => $GLOBALS[asides_id]
) );
$rand_keys = array_rand($categories, 4);
foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {
$cats .= $categories[$key]->term_id .',';
}
wp_list_categories('title_li=&include='.$cats);

Comment: @ElahinMiah
Yes, it's like that.

Comment: @RobinHasan Dear, i have added that in single.php but nothing happended :(